# 403 when trying to route to Angular app in S3 using path-based routing

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

My project has a simple static website as the root (literally a single index.html file) and and Angular app that should be displayed with the user clicks on a navigation link. I have configured CloudFront + S3 using OAC as described in [this AWS blog post](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website).

It works perfectly fine for the root website. For example when the user navigates to mydomain.com the basic static website displays as expected. **The problem I am having is when the user attempts to navigate to mydomain.com/myApp I get a 403 Access Denied.**

On the S3 side I have individual buckets for the root app and the Angular app.
The file structure for the Angular app in S3 is `MyBucket/myApp/Angular build files`.
The bucket policy in place is the default policy that AWS provides when you assign the OAC from CloudFront, shown below:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket>/*",
                "arn:aws:s3::: <my-bucket>/myApp/*" <--Added as attempt to solve 403
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::<numbers>:distribution/<id>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

On the CloudFront side I have a single distribution with the default origin pointing to the S3 bucket with the basic static website (index.html file) and an additional origin pointing to the S3 bucket with the Angular app.

In addition, I have configured a Behaviors pattern with a Path Pattern = `myApp/*` with the origin= S3 bucket with Angular app and "viewer Protocol Policy=`HTTP & HTTPS`. All other configuration in the Behavior pattern were left at default.

On the Angular side I have configured the app to use a `base href="/myApp/"`

I've tried so many different AWS configurations like setting an `origin path = /myApp` in CloudFront, setting `Viewer Protocol Policy= redirect HTTP to HTTPS`. I've tried flattening the directory structure in S3 to remove the `myApp` dir and have all the Angular build files at the root. I've been hitting dead ends all over and haven't been able to find a solution on StackOverflow or broader internet. I may just be asking the wrong questions, but I'm really stuck here. Any solutions or insight are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at the reference implementation here: [Amazon Cloudfront Secure Static Site](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-secure-static-site#user-content-amazon-cloudfront-secure-static-website)?

Comment: Did this get resolved?

Answer (score 1):

`"arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket>/*"` is enough. `"arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket>/myApp/*"` is a subset of the first.

You have a different issue here. To solve the issue you can use 1. or 2. from the below:

1. Use Edge lambda for VIEWER_REQUEST events to `redirect` requests to index.html

```js
"use strict";
const map = {
  "/myApp": "/index.html",
  "/other/path": "/index.html",
};


// eslint-disable-next-line
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  // Extract the request from the CloudFront event that is sent to Lambda@Edge
  const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

  // Extract the URI from the request
  const oldUri = request.uri;
  const newUri =
    map[
      oldUri.endsWith("/") ? oldUri.substring(0, oldUri.length - 1) : oldUri
    ] || oldUri;
  // Log the URI as received by CloudFront and the new URI to be used to fetch from origin
  // console.log("map", { oldUri, newUri });
  // Replace the received URI with the URI that includes the index page
  request.uri = newUri;
  // Return to CloudFront
  return callback(null, request);
};
```

2. Pre-generate and upload your site in a different way.
   CouldFront literally requires `path/to/something` object to be present at S3 for urls like https://host/path/to/something.
   So you can use something similar to 'react-snap' for Angular to generate static HTML for all required paths and upload the correct structure to s3.

Mind that for object `s3://bucket/path/index.html` the https://host/path will not work with CloudFront. CloudFront needs to have `s3://bucket/path` where `path` has content of `index.html`

Comment: Attempting to use solution (1) and it isn't working. Still get a 403. Maybe a configuration issue on my end, but I'll try to debug it further.

Comment: Hi @Narm, how does your S3 object list looks like?

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the Angular bucket does not match the website name (which it cannot, because your root bucket apparently does) then the Angular bucket should be declared in CloudFront as a custom (rather than S3) origin.

Also, make sure that CORS is enabled on the Angular bucket (I assume it is configured as a website).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is to deploy the Angular app to a folder within the main app's bucket. Then tell Cloudfront how to resolve files for individual HTTP requests via a lambda edge extension. Here is one way of doing that:

```
import {Context} from 'aws-lambda';

const handler = async (event: any, context: Context) => {

    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const requestUri = request.uri.toLowerCase();

    // First serve files for known extensions
    const extensions = [
        '.html',
        '.js',
        '.css',
        '.ico',
    ];

    const knownExtension = extensions.find((ext) => {
        return requestUri.endsWith(`${ext}`);
    });

    if (knownExtension) {
        return request;
    }

    const demoAppBasePath = '/demoapp/';
    if (requestUri.startsWith(demoAppBasePath)) {
        
        // Serve the demoapp index.html for other requests within that path
        request.uri = `${demoAppBasePath}index.html`;
        return request;

    } else {

        // Serve the shellapp index.html for any other requests
        request.uri = '/index.html';
        return request;
    };
};

export {handler};
```

More info on this topic is acailable in my blog posts, and may give you some ideas for your own solution:

- [Static content delivery](https://authguidance.com/cdn-static-content-delivery/)
- [Cloudfront extensions](https://authguidance.com/lambda-edge-spa-extensions/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure my solution is exactly the same but I have an Angular app that uses static assets in another bucket. I was able to have the same cloudfront serve both up by adding multiple origins
[image]

then setting up 2 behaviors

[image]

From what I understand from your post I would try setting up another bucket for your Angular app and add it as a 2nd origin with a behavior set to redirect /myApp/* to the new origin.